# Problem to detect security script like X-Frame through .htaccess file in WordPress and how to trace and find the problem?

Tags: htaccess, web-hosting, wordpress, security

I transferred my WordPress website from a hosting company to a virtual machine. I want to add some security scripts like X-Frame, CSP, and HSTS. Before that, I edited the .htaccess file from the cPanel and it worked well. Now, I added the same script in the current .htaccess file in the VM but when I check with this site X-Frame Online Check, I received a "Couldn't find X-Frame" message.

```
Couldn't find the X-Frame-Options headers in the response headers.
```

This is my .haccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDo>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

How can I find the problem and trace this issue?

Comment: Is mod_headers installed? You should remove the `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` wrappers. There is certainly an error in the `STS` header line (it's truncated). You are missing the closing `</IfModule>`. Are _inner_ WordPress pages working OK using pretty permalinks?

Comment: "This is my .haccess file:" - Best check... this is just a typo in your question and not a typo in the filename?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some steps to troubleshoot:

1. Is the htaccess working? Perhaps your Apache server has a **AllowOverride None** directive. A simple test would be to enter some erroneous code, like **XYZ** and see if it throws an error.
2. Do you have mod_headers installed? As Per MrWhite's suggestion, remove the **IfModule mod_headers.c** and see if it throws an error.
3. I noticed that there's a typo on your HSTS header. Also know that you can combine several into a single block. Try replacing both of your header statements with the following (I've added a few common ones):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>     Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
>     Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
>     Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
>     Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
>     Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
> </IfModule>
> ```